# HTML Form Submit not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

On submitting this form, I am not getting any parameter values on the action page. With GET I am not getting any parameters in the URL. I have also tried using POST but it is transferring no data.

This HTML code is included in a JSP page and I have tried using a test form from the same JSP with a single input field inside that form and that is working fine. So maybe the issue is with the code included in this form.

```
    <form id="mainForm" action="partnerProfileInsert.jsp" method="GET">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div id="compulsoryDetails" class="fleft">
                <div class="mainDivs">
                    <div>Select F_Partner</div>
                    <div style="align:center">
                        <select id="fPartner" name="fPartner">
                            <option value="evolution">evolution</option>
                            <option value="evolutionreport">evolutionreport</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="mainDivs">
                    <div>
                        Please input the BrandName to be added:
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="brandName" name="brandName" class="brandName">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="mainDivs">
                    <div>
                        Please input the F_Account_ID :
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="fAccountId" name="fAccountId">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="mainDivs">
                    <div>
                        Please input the F_URL :
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="fUrl" name="fUrl">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="margin-left:200px">
                    <button type="button" id="firstStepProceed" onclick="firstProceed()">Next>></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hiddenDetails" class="fright" style="display:none">
                <div style="color:red">
                    Please Review thw PreFilled Details and Click <a href="javascript:enableDiv('hiddenDetails')">here</a> if you want to Change any Value:
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_PARTNER_PROFILE_ID:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fPartnerProfileId" name="fPartnerProfileId">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_MODE:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fMode" name="fMode">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_IS_ACTIVE:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fIsActive" name="fIsActive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">F_PASSWORD:</div>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left:300px">
                        <input type="password" id="fPassword" name="fPassword">
                        <input type="text" id="fPasswordText" style="display:none" name="fPasswordText">
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:210px">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="showHide" onchange="passwordShow()" />
                        <label for="showHide" id="showHideLabel">Show Password</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_SECRET_KEY:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fSecretKey" name="fSecretKey">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_CHECK_MD5:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fCheckMD5" name="fCheckMD5">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_CUSTOM1_NAME:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fCustom1Name" name="fCustom1Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_CUSTOM1:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fCustom1" name="fCustom1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_CUSTOM2_NAME:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fCustom2Name" name="fCustom2Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_CUSTOM2:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fCustom2" name="fCustom2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_PRODUCT:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fProduct" name="fProduct">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <div style="float:left">
                        F_SERVICE:
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-right:380px">
                        <input type="text" id="fService" name="fService">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="mainProceed" style="display:none" align="center">
                <button type="button" style="float:left;margin-left:800px;width:80px" onclick="backFromRightDiv()">back</button>
                <button type="button" style="float:right;margin-right:600px" onclick="proceedToSummary()">proceed>></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="summaryDiv" style="display:none">
            <div id="summaryTable"></div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div>
                <button type="button" onclick="backfromSummary()">back</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Add"></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function firstStepCheck(){
if(blankCheck("brandName")&&
blankCheck("fAccountId")&&
blankCheck("fUrl"))
return true;
else
return false;
}
function blankCheck(element){
var elemValue = document.getElementById(element).value.trim();
if(elemValue==""){
alert(element+" cannot be left Empty!!");
document.getElementById(element).focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
function firstProceed(){
if(!firstStepCheck())
return;
}
</script>
```

Comment: spacing my friend  `name ="" => name="" `. `name =""` is two arguments so you have nothing assigned to name prop

Comment: sorry i am not able to understand..what you meant to say..
is name = "brandName" and name =  "brandName" different?

Comment: yes, when you separate them, it will be considered as two different attributes. so name = "brandName" is on browser three properties `'name'=null`, `'='=null`, `'"brandName"'=null`

Comment: please post entire code.what firstProceed() function is doing?

Comment: I don't think the spacing is the issue here. In HTML it is still valid to put `name="theName"` or `name = "theName"` as long there is an equal and you use quotes (single or double). The issue here looks more on the javascript part which is missing in the code extract.

Comment: For proving my latest comment you can play to add or not space in the [W3C Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_text) and the result is always the same.

Comment: Fixed your formatting

Comment: yeah spacing seems  to be handles by HTML itself..for all those who want to know JS code i am adding it

Comment: Hi this is solved...i had one requirement in which i was disabling the elements in this form..and it seems disabled inputs are not sent in POST or GET request. now i have made them to readOnly and its working fine.
Thank you all for your inputs